# Adding jitter on a log transformed axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm learning more about ggplot and came across a situation where I had to use jitter on a sqrt transformed axis where some values were '0'. Since you can't take the sqrt of a negative number the following argument was added to the code:

`ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y),data=df) + geom_jitter(alpha=0.1, position = position_jitter(h=0)).`

Any idea how to perform a similar operation on a log scale? For some reason I thought changing the argument: position_jitter(h=1) would do the trick, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `h` is short for `height` and stands for the magnitude of the vertical noise (e.g. the noise on the y-axis) that `jitter` adds to the data; in both positive and negative direction. 
I guess, in the your data set, `h=0` was used to prevent the y-values to become negative, so that the `sqrt` function could be applied.

To set `h=1` in the case of a log-transformation would therefore not make sense. If your original y-values are all positive, then `h=0` would do the trick for the same reason as in the `sqrt` case.

If some y-values are 0 (or even negative), then you cannot apply the log-function anyway.

Comment: Makes sense, so the only way to make it work would be to subset out data <1. So in the case of the sqrt scenario, this would imply that ggplot is using default jitter for the x-direction, correct?

Comment: Yes, by default, the function geom_jitter applies noise both in x and y direction. In the documentation it says: "If omitted, defaults to 40% of the resolution of the data: this means the jitter values will occupy 80% of the implied bins. " So, for instance, if your points lie 10 points away from each other, the noise will be up to +-4.